# Can't figure out what's going on with RegExp question mark

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match sets of digits preceded by a dot, or nothing at all. I came up with the regular expression `(?:\.\d+)?`. However, it will match the string `.` even though the quantifier on `\d` is a plus. If I get rid of the last question mark, which I believe is making the group optional since there is no preceding quantifier, then it works fine. I am using the RegExp engine in JavaScript, specifically `node.js` in this case.

Here's what I got from my testing:

- `.123`, without optional: true
- `.`, without optional: false
- empty, without optional: false
- `.123`, with optional: true
- `.`, with optional: true
- empty, with optional: true
- `.123`, expected: true
- `.`, expected: false
- empty, expected: true

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add whether or not those test cases should be matched (the expected output). Something like: _.123, without optional: true, should be matched_...

Comment: You are making the whole capture group optional and that's basically your expression. There's nothing required to appear on the string (everything is optional) so any string goes.

Comment: Wouldn't `/(\.\d+)/` be sufficient? (Or `/\.(\d+)/` if you don't want to capture the dot?)

Comment: @DanielBeck Ha I just added that to my answer, the OP was definitely overcomplicating things :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add ^ and $ markers to the regex like so

```
^(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Otherwise it would match an empty string at any point in the string.

Comment: Wut, how is this even an answer?

Comment: @BoxTechy how does this answer your question? This will still match the `.`

Comment: @Clonkex The OP wants to match an empty string or a single dot followed by one or more digits, which this answer achieves.

Comment: @JordanGray OH, right. I completely misunderstood the question. This answer is indeed correct (and actually means mine is incorrect).

Comment: @Clonkex It's okay—regular expressions are almost as hard to describe as they are to write! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
/^<your regex>$/
```

as a general rule to make sure that your entire string is matched. Right now your regex allows the empty string which can be matched at any point.

Note that

```
/(?:\.\d+)?/.test('a') === true
```

and the regex will match any nonempty string.

Comment: `/^(?:\.\d+)?$/.test('')` will also be true